# SQL - Multiple Values comma separated when using GROUP BY

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have data that looks like

> ```
> CUSTOMER,  CUSTOMER_ID, PRODUCT
> ABC INC    1            XYX
> ABC INC    1            ZZZ
> DEF CO     2            XYX
> DEF CO     2            ZZZ
> DEF CO     2            WWW
> GHI LLC    3            ZYX
> ```

I'd like to write a query that'd make the data look like this:

> ```
> CUSTOMER, CUSTOMER_ID, PRODUCTS
> ABC INC   1            XYX, ZZZ
> DEF CO    2            XYX, ZZZ, WWW
> GHI LLC   3            ZYX
> ```

Using Oracle 10g if helps.  I saw something that would work using MYSQL, but I need a plain SQL or ORACLE equivalent.   I've also seen examples of stored procs that could be made, however, I cannot use a stored proc with the product i'm using.

Here's how'd it work in MySQL if I were using it

```
SELECT CUSTOMER, 
       CUSTOMER_ID, 
       GROUP_CONCAT( PRODUCT ) 
FROM MAGIC_TABLE 
GROUP BY CUSTOMER, CUSTOMER_ID
```

Thank you.

Comment: How to do the Same in SQL Server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This link](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/StringAggregationTechniques.php) refers to a number of examples of different ways to do this on Oracle.  See if there's something there that you have permissions on your database to do.

Comment: -1 because this answer is useless on it's own. Please consider improving your answer by summarizing the content in the link in case the link becomes invalid in the future.

Answer (score 22):

I think LISTAGG is the best aggregate group by function to use in this situation:

```
  SELECT CUSTOMER, CUSTOMER_ID,
         LISTAGG(PRODUCT, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY PRODUCT)
    FROM SOME_TABLE
GROUP BY CUSTOMER, CUSTOMER_ID
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

Comment: LISTAGG is not availble in 10g.

Answer (score 3):

The oracle user function 'wm_concat' works the same way as LISTAGG except you cannot specify a delimiter ',' by default or a sort order. It is however compatible with 10g.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Nigel,

My SQL is not as elegant as could be, but I needed a solution that required SQL only, not PLSQL or TSQL, so it ended up looking like this:

```
SELECT   CUSTOMER, CUSTOMER_ID, COUNT(PRODUCT) PROD_COUNT, 
         RTRIM( 
            XMLAGG( XMLELEMENT (C, PRODUCT || ',') ORDER BY PRODUCT
).EXTRACT ('//text()'), ',' 
         ) AS PRODUCTS FROM     (
         SELECT   DISTINCT CUSTOMER, CUSTOMER_ID, PRODUCT
         FROM     MAGIC_TABLE
         ) GROUP BY CUSTOMER, CUSTOMER_ID ORDER BY 1 , 2
```

Still not exactly sure what the XML functions do exactly, but I'll dig in when the need arrises.