# Oracle - Subquery with concat possible?

Tags: sql, oracle

is it possible to concat the result of an subquery with oracle?

if this subquery for an view:

```
  (SELECT s.name
        FROM
            app_shared_servers ass
        LEFT JOIN servers s
            ON (s.srv_id = ass.srv_id) WHERE ass.app_id = a.APP_ID) SHARED_SERVERS
```

Which returns a list of servernames associated with some kind of system. I need them to display like "Server, Server2, Server3" inside the view.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this looks like a string aggregation question, see these questions on SO for a description of available methods:

- [Oracle: Combine multiple results in a subquery into a single comma-separated value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492563/oracle-combine-multiple-results-in-a-subquery-into-a-single-comma-separated-valu)
- [Add comma-separated value of grouped rows to existing query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042885/add-comma-separated-value-of-grouped-rows-to-existing-query)
- [SQL - Multiple Values comma separated when using GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234532/sql-multiple-values-comma-separated-when-using-group-by)